# Printing registry info to obtain the stack location GDB

Tags: assembly, gdb, stack-trace

How do I print out multiple values on the stack at once while examining a C binary in GDB? I want output similar to the following:

```
0xbfc3ff70:     0xb7f4bff4      0xb7f89ce0      0x00000000      0xbfc3ff98
0xbfc3ff80:     0xb7e4c943      0xb7f4c4e0      0x08048930      0xbfc3ffa4
0xbfc3ff90:     0xbfc3ffa4      0xb7f4bff4      0xbfc3ffb8      0x08048625
0xbfc3ffa0:     0x08048930      0xb7f81660      0x00000000      0xbfc45318
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use $sp to reference the stack register, printf to print values from the stack (as you would in C), and from there it's just a matter of casting the arguments to printf:

```
db $ printf "[%08X] 0x%08X 0x%08X 0x%08X 0x%08X\n", \
    $sp,                        \
    *(unsigned int *) $sp,      \
    *(unsigned int *)($sp + 4), \
    *(unsigned int *)($sp + 8), \
    *(unsigned int *)($sp +12)
[FFFFE080] 0x00000000 0x00000000 0xF7A3C76D 0x00000000
db $
```

You should of course wrap this in a function. e.g.

```
define stackdump
    printf... # show bytes 0-15
    printf... # show bytes 15-31
    printf... # show bytes 32-47
end
```

...and stick it in your ~/.gdbinit so it will be available every time you run gdb.